# Using Google Map in Android application

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to use Google Maps in my Android application, but I don't know how to start. I know that I need to use `MapActivity`, `MapView` and I realize that there are 3 versions of the api.
The map view needs a api key. So I have couple questions:

- How can I generate this api key?
- Is it free?
- There is a tutorial that explain the very beginning of using this feature? (from the api key to use it on activity)

Thanks.

Comment: [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html) and [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can find two versions of Google maps API for android. v1 is deprecated and has alot of limitations.Use v2 o develop apps.
And regarding the API key:
You can gind it documented well here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key
Also here is the official guide for using the new Maps API
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro

And adding to that, you need not necessarily use MapActivity. You should use mapFragments instead.